# Unrecognized escape sequence \P while parsing the data using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using below properties and powershell script to parse the data from properties file. But it is failing while trying to read backslash character "\" in the datasource string. I tried to fix it by adding additional backslash in the properties file. But I am looking for the solution to handle it in powershell instead of making any changes in the properties file.

```
#env.properties value
datasource=SERVER.SUBDOMAIN.SUBDOMAIN2.DOMAIN.TLD\PWDFC1;initialcatalog=SAA;Trusted_Connection=True;MultiSubnetFailover=True

#Powershell Script
$EnvProps='C:\Apps\SAA\config\env.properties'
$AppConfig= 'C:\Apps\SAA\config\app.config'
$ReadProps = convertfrom-stringdata ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($EnvProps))
  foreach($key in $ReadProps.Keys)
  {
   $value = $ReadProps[$key]
   (Get-Content $AppConfig) -replace "@@$key@@", $value | Set-Content $AppConfig
 }

Error while running above script

INFO   2021-08-30 14:22:37    Executing command ...
INFO   2021-08-30 14:22:37    
ERROR   2021-08-30 14:22:53    convertfrom-stringdata : parsing "data 
source=SERVER.SUBDOMAIN.SUBDOMAIN2.DOMAIN.TLD\PWDFC1;initial
ERROR   2021-08-30 14:22:53    catalog=SAA;Trusted_Connection=True;MultiSubnetFailover=True" - 
Unrecognized escape sequence \P.
```

Comment: Remove the space between`$ReadProps .Keys`

Comment: Thanks for noticing it , I removed it from here. Original script don't have space.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape backslashes in the data string. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7.1):

> `ConvertFrom-StringData` supports escape character sequences that are allowed by conventional machine translation tools.... the cmdlet can interpret backslashes (`\`) as escape characters.... instead of the PowerShell backtick character (`` ` ``) that would normally signal the end of a line in a script. Inside the here-string, the backtick character does not work.

Further mentioned in the link above, it supports escape sequences which are used by regular expressions. You can escape your string prior to putting it through `ConvertFrom-StringData` by using the `[regex]::Escape(string)` static method. This will automatically escape any expression tokens in your data so they are parsed literally.

---

You also need separate each key and value so they fit on their own line, though this is something you will run into once you resolve the error above. Alternatively, you can split on the semi-colon `;` prior to running the string through `ConvertFrom-StringData`. This is also mentioned in the [cmdlet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7.1).

In the end, the data string you pass to `ConvertFrom-StringData` should look like this:

```
datasource=SERVER.SUBDOMAIN.SUBDOMAIN2.DOMAIN.TLD\\PWDFC1
initialcatalog=SAA
Trusted_Connection=True
MultiSubnetFailover=True
```

### Edit

I missed this on the first go, but you also need to remove the semi-colons `;` from the string before using `ConvertFrom-StringData`. This won't cause any errors, but the `;` will be included as part of the value, which is likely undesirable. I have updated the sample data above to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for providing these information. I have never tried using this method to escape the string in the file before  using ConvertFrom-String. Could you please share any sample which could escape similar string that I have used in my case. DataSERVER.SUBDOMAIN.SUBDOMAIN2.DOMAIN.TLD\PWDFC1;initialcatalog=SAA;Trusted_Connection=True;MultiSubnetFailover=True

Comment: The wording is a bit confusing so the documentation isn't clear on whether all regex tokens are attempted to be parsed, or only the escape sequences. If you find `[regex]::Escape` gives you issues on some special characters, you can try just replacing ``\`` with ``\\`` in the data string.

Comment: I think you edited your comment after I read it, didn't see the part about how to use the Escape method. Literally just pass the data string in as read from the file into `[regex]::Escape(string)` as a parameter, and pass the escaped string to `ConvertFrom-StringData`